# Automating CIS Hardening benchmarks for Windows Server

Tags: windows, security

It seems that CIS benchmarks on Hardening for Windows Server is more then 700 pages and if there are multitude of servers, doing manually is a challenge.

I wonder, how does one really automate the entire process for windows, maybe via some kind of configuration tools or different way ?

We tried going the ready made AMI way, but challenge is that lot of things do not seem to work and we can't even trace on which CIS rule caused the break because there are too many rules.

Any suggestions will be appreciated !

Comment: Have you find something reg. this?

Comment: I had the same question. I am going through this exact same requirement now. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can test [HardeningKitty](https://github.com/scipag/HardeningKitty), a Powershell script.
As a commercial solution I suggest [CHEF](https://community.chef.io/)

HardeningKitty is a open source Powershell script using CIS and other Security checklists as a csv database and Audit your windows 10 and windows server security settings. In addition to Audit, it can make Hardening on your machine.

HardeningKitty works in Three modes: Audit, HailMary and Config.

Before you make use of it, run powershell as Administrator, then you must import ./Invoke as a module and acitivate execuation of unsigned scripts on Powershell.

```
>     Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
> Import-Module .\Invoke-HardeningKitty.ps1
```

after that make Audition using following command:

```
> Invoke-HardeningKitty -Mode Audit -FileFindingList .\lists\finding_list_cis_microsoft_windows_server_2012_r2_2.4.0_machine.csv
```

you can change security checklist using csv files in **HardeningKitty\lists** directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29957118)

Comment: Hardening kitty seems like a very interesting option. Can't wait to try it. Did anyone try? Does it cover all the CIS benchmark rules?